# В переопределенном стиле DataGrid не работает BorderThicness

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

У меня есть измененный стиль для DataGrid

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{DynamicResource DataGridCellStyle1}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="RowStyle" Value="{DynamicResource DataGridRowStyle1}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="None"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="0"></Setter>
 
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false">
                        <ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Button Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}" Focusable="false" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
 
                                    <Border x:Name="border" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=(local:Custom_DataGrid.BackgroundColumnHeaders)}"
                                             BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" 
                                            CornerRadius="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=(local:Custom_DataGrid.CornerRadius_ColumnHeaders)}" Grid.Column="1">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <!--<Rectangle Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" RadiusX="6" RadiusY="6"></Rectangle>-->
                                            <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
 
                                    <Border x:Name="Borders"  Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=(local:Custom_DataGrid.MarginContentPanel)}"
                                             Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=(local:Custom_DataGrid.BackgroundContent)}" 
                                             Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"></ScrollContentPresenter>
                                        <Border.Clip>
                                            <RectangleGeometry 
                                                        RadiusX="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=(local:Custom_DataGrid.CornerRadius_ContentPanel)}" 
                                                        RadiusY="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=(local:Custom_DataGrid.CornerRadius_ContentPanel)}">
                                                <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RectConverter}">
                                                        <Binding ElementName="Borders" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                                        <Binding ElementName="Borders" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                                                    </MultiBinding>
                                                </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                                            </RectangleGeometry>
                                        </Border.Clip>
                                    </Border>
 
                                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=(local:Custom_DataGrid.MarginContentPanel)}"
                                            Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Orientation="Vertical" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Orientation="Horizontal" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ScrollViewer.Template>
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"></ItemsPresenter>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Если для элемента с именем `border` я указываю BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" то заголовок таблицы исчезает, пример на скриншоте. Не пойму почему из за указания свойств может исчезать контент с заголовками столбцов

```
<Border x:Name="border" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=(local:Custom_DataGrid.BackgroundColumnHeaders)}"
                                             BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" 
                                            CornerRadius="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=(local:Custom_DataGrid.CornerRadius_ColumnHeaders)}" Grid.Column="1">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <!--<Rectangle Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" RadiusX="6" RadiusY="6"></Rectangle>-->
                                            <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]